# White view when launch iOS app in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, simulator

I have been working for 4 months on an app, its pretty complex and works fine.
Now suddenly, I added a new class and did some changes to the MainWindow.xib with all my views there and now I just get a plain white view when I launch it with simulator.
I even stripped it down completely to nothing but the appdelegate and one simple plain view with a button. So basically I've got an app with nothing but an appDelegate managing a tabBar, launching with one simple view, no frameworks no nothing and I still get a white app.

There must be an option somewhere that I must have activated for the running of app in simulator but I can't figure it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if you have forget to add the root view controller to the main window, either by `[self.window addSubview:yourRootViewController.view]`, or by `self.window.rootViewController = yourRootViewController;` (*Note: If you are doing it by code*).

And, you are seeing the white color because main window's `backgroundColor` is `white`.

Comment: But I do have [self.window.rootViewController=self.tabBarController]; and then [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; Where's the other linkage supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

I realized I never explained how I got it working after all, long time ago:
Bad linking of the window, as EmptyStack directed me to, but it wasn't in the code, it was in the view properties in the Interface builder. I had set the Type of the window to be the class that should have been the controller of the window, not the type (: